# Use putexcel to insert a string in Excel

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I am trying to make an easy to use `do` file where the user inserts the names of the towns s/he wants to `summarize` and then Stata:

- summarizes the towns
- saves the results in an Excel file
- exports the names of the towns summarized

I am using a list saved in a local macro since it works well with the `inlist()` function:

```
clear
input Date AskingRent str10 Town
2019 12 Boston 
2019 13 Cambridge
2018 14 Boston
2018 15 Cambridge
end

local towns `" "Billerica", "Boston" "'
keep if inlist(City, `towns')
***some analysis

putexcel set "results.xlsx", modify
putexcel A1 = `towns'
```

I want the Excel file to have "Billerica, Boston" in cell `A1`.

However, I get an error in the last line of code that says:

> nothing found where expression expected

Comment: Nathan, please read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for advice on how to ask Stata-related questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
clear
input foo1 str20 foo2
5 "Billerica"
6 "Boston"
7 "London"
8 "New York"
end

. local towns `" "Billerica", "Boston" "'
. keep if inlist(foo2, `towns')

. putexcel set "results.xlsx", modify
. putexcel A1 = `"`towns'"'
file results.xlsx saved
```